# Validate client certificate in Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, x509certificate

Java application is using Spring Boot 3 and Java 17 having some REST API exposed. When the API call is made, only for specific endpoint, I want to extract the client certificate and validate it.

**Curl command to call the API :**

```
curl -X POST "https://localhost:8443/api/auth" \
    -H "accept: */*" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "skv_client_correlation_id: xyz" \
    -d '{"xyz": "xyz"}' \
    --cert client_public_certificate.crt \
    --key client_private_key.key \
    --cacert server_public_certificate.crt
```

Before upgrading to Spring boot 3, in Spring boot 2 the client certificate was validated by  :

```
public class CertificateFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final KeyStore keyStore;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
        @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
        @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    )
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
            );
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

            for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
                if (trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager x509TrustManager) {
                    x509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, "RSA");
                }
            }
        } catch (CertificateException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.warn("Invalid certificate: {}", e.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Invalid certificate");
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error during certificate validation: {}", e.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error during certificate validation");
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

After upgrading spring boot 3 the request does not contain "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" and does not contain "jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate" attribute (i.e the certs is always null). May I know how to validate the client certificate only for specific endpoint?

Comment: Which web server are you using? It should be able to do this for you without the need for your own filter.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I am using Tomcat web server

Comment: How have you configured SSL? Setting `server.ssl.client-auth=need` will require clients to provide a trusted certificate. You'll also have to configure a trust store (there are `server.ssl.*` properties for that too) so that Tomcat knows which certificates to trust.

Comment: You tagged your question with Spring Security, but I don't see that you are using Spring Security. Instead you wrote some custom code. Are you using Spring Security? If yes, why are you writing some custom code?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson in these properties server.ssl.key-store and trust.store I would to mention the contents of the file (i.e base64 contents of .p12 files). Is there a way how to do that?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, can you also please let me know how to achieve this for specfic endpoint instead of for all endpoints?